# Set up for Android Studio gets stuck

Tags: ubuntu, java, android

I was setting up my freshly installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04, 
when it was time to set up Android Studio 3.0 I came across this:
[image]

it appears that the setup tries to download from
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
repeatedly, i think it fails inside.

When i tried the URL in my browser, it works though.
Anyone familiar with this issue?

[SUPPLEMENT]
• Java Version : 8u152
• Executed : sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386

Comment: Note: I have same issue with a Mac today. same file.

Comment: After 5?minutes the install *seemed* to go through (not sure though if it just timed out... but at least starting downloading rest of files) ... now stuck on sdk-tools-darwin-###.zip and went through after few minutes... now stuck again at emulator-darwin-4266726.zip, then build_tools_r27-macosx.zip. then on google_m2repository_gms_v11_3_rc05_wear_2_0_5.zip.... and then platform-27-r01.zip and so on... Will report back if it actually still installed everything and works.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem. It was stuck there for a few minutes. I then did an Internet search and it brought me to this page. As soon as I got to this page the installation started to proceed, but then started getting stuck on emulator-windows-4266726.zip.

Comment: Patience is key when you have deadlines. :*

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and after a few minutes it continued with other files, and doing the same repeating status with other files. I suspect because these are very large files that it's only (poorly) displaying status. Patience is critical, especially if you have a slower Internet connection, or you should completely ignore the details page and just look at the status bar.

Answer (score 4):

Just wait it out, it will eventually finish. The status display seems to be completely broken.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have installed it on Debian with [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-android-studio-on-debian-9-stretch-linux) without any hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

Be patient.  Its downloading.

If it helps your mind, run the following command to see the TCP traffic.  It will show the traffic for https (port 443).

`sudo tcpdump port 443 -i en0`

```
00:10:29.291315 IP 74.125.136.190.https > 192.168.1.20.49919: Flags [.], seq 35550648:35552066, ack 606, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 1672373960 ecr 50627133], length 1418
00:10:29.291321 IP 74.125.136.190.https > 192.168.1.20.49919: Flags [.], seq 35552066:35553484, ack 606, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 1672373960 ecr 50627133], length 1418
00:10:29.298028 IP 74.125.136.190.https > 192.168.1.20.49919: Flags [.], seq 35553484:35554902, ack 606, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 1672373966 ecr 50627138], length 1418
00:10:29.298289 IP 74.125.136.190.https > 192.168.1.20.49919: Flags [.], seq 35554902:35556320, ack 606, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 1672373966 ecr 50627138], length 1418
00:10:29.298344 IP 192.168.1.20.49919 > 74.125.136.190.https: Flags [.], ack 35556320, win 32590, options [nop,nop,TS val 50627164 ecr 1672373945], length 0
00:10:29.312330 IP 74.125.136.190.https > 192.168.1.20.49919: Flags [.], seq 35556320:35557738, ack 606, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 1672373995 ecr 50627164], length 1418
00:10:29.312561 IP 74.125.136.190.https > 192.168.1.20.49919: Flags [.], seq 35557738:35559156, ack 606, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 1672373995 ecr 50627164], length 1418
00:10:29.319361 IP 74.125.136.190.https > 192.168.1.20.49919: Flags [.], seq 35559156:35560574, ack 606, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 1672373995 ecr 50627164], length 1418
```

It took about 10mins on my mac.